# @viewchild dropdown is coming as undefined in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

**app.component.ts**

```
        import { Component, ViewChild ,AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
        import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

          @ViewChild("dropdown1", { static: false }) dropdown: ElementRef;
          ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            console.log(this.dropdown)
          }
        }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <app-child></app-child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
    })
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

    }
```

**child.component.html**

```
    <select  #dropdown1>
      <option value="1">
          Text1
      </option>
      <option value="2">
        Text2
    </option>
    </select>
```

Point 1
I am trying to access child element dropdown in parent using 
@viewchild but dropdown is coming null in parent comopnent in ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook

Point 2 After access dropdown in parent I want to set particular option of dropdown in parent...

Comment: Where you has your template reference? you only can access from the component. That's if your `#dropdown1`is in childComponent, you need declare the ViewChild in your childComponent `<<app-child #child></app-child>`; `@ViewChild('child',{static:false} child:any` to get some like this.child.dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You have to see the child component first. The child component has to see the dropdown. So in child component make a method that show the dropdown and call it from the father in ngAfterViewInit method that respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

```
1)
            import { Component, ViewChild ,AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
            import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-root',
              templateUrl: './app.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
            })
            export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

              @ViewChild('dropdown1', { static: true }) child: ChildComponent;

              ngAfterViewInit(): void {
                this.child.dropdown();
              }
            }

        2) app.component.html
        <app-child></app-child>

        3)import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-child',
          templateUrl: './child.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
        })
        export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor() { }

          @ViewChild(ElementRef, { static: true }) dropdown: ElementRef;

          ngOnInit(): void {
          }

          dropdown(){
            console.log(this.dropdown);
          }

        }
       4.child.component.html

        <select  #dropdown1>
          <option value="1">
              Text1
          </option>
          <option value="2">
            Text2
        </option>
        </select>
```